# Firebase rules, deny edits after initial write, write depend on value

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I got an "object" on my realtime database.

```
-MHHP5ZSmLKG_xeA9SLJ
    0NThxhcHIPgOJGZC1MyE3Fg0NUc2
    XCEI5dQxP8YxaChrF5O061eyFv32
    creatorID: "7Pao7pDRaFUVWM9c234Qq44UwoE3"
    message: "I wish I knew, why the world is is getting craz..."
    messageID: "-MHHP5ZSmLKG_xeA9SLJ"
    timestamp: 1600184270739
    timestampReverse: 998399815846742
```

Two questions.

Is there a way for me to make it, such that creatorID: can't be written to after the original initialization.

```
"creatorID" : {
    .write : "false"
}
```

Does this work, or would it also block initial write? Essentially I'm looking to make it unable to be edited.

And is there a way to writea rule such that only if auth.uid and creatorID.value is equal, can you edit the message:

```
"message" : {
    .write : "auth.uid == creatorID.value"
}
```

Best regards,
Sam

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `creatorID` field to only be writeable upon creation, you can do:

```
"creatorID" : {
    .write : "!data.exists()"
}
```

If you want the `message` field to only be writeable by its original author, that'd be:

```
"message" : {
    .write : "auth.uid == data.child('creatorID').val()"
}
```

Comment: Another question. If I have a general rule for a section, then add a specific rule within that section. Does the most specific rule take president? Like:

{
 "rules": {
  "allQuestions": {
   ".indexOn": "timestampReverse",
   ".read": "auth != null",
   ".write": "auth != null",
                        "creatorID" : {
                         .write : "!data.exists()"
                        }
  },